# Flutter Sorting JSON by States

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to sort my Json by the key (States (Billing).

This is the json.

**accounts.json**

```
{
  "Accounts": [
    {
      "Name": "Klinik Pakar Mata & Surgeri Tg.Kamal",
      "TPA Customer ID": "9708",
      "Organization Type": "Clinic",
      "Organization Subtype": "GP",
      "Street (Billing)": "22-1, Jalan Tanjong Laboh, Kampung Bahagia, 83000 Batu Pahat, Johor, Malaysia",
      "City (Billing)": "batu pahat",
      "State (Billing)": "Johor",
      "Coordinate" : {
        "Latitude" : "1.846280",
        "Longitude" : "102.938568"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "KLINIK RS SHIVA SDN.BHD",
      "TPA Customer ID": "740",
      "Organization Type": "Clinic",
      "Organization Subtype": "GP",
      "Street (Billing)": "No 3, Medan 23, Bandar Baru Salak Tinggi",
      "City (Billing)": "Sepang",
      "Postal Code (Billing)": "43900",
      "State (Billing)": "Selangor",
      "Country (Billing)": "Malaysia",
      "Coordinate" : {
        "Latitude" : "1.846280",
        "Longitude" : "102.938568"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the model class of the json file

**accounts_model.dart**

```
class Accounts{

  List<AccountInfo> accountinfo;

  Accounts({this.accountinfo});

  factory Accounts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){

    var accJson = json["Accounts"] as List;
    List<AccountInfo> accList = accJson.map((i) => AccountInfo.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return Accounts(
      accountinfo: accList
    );
  }
}

class AccountInfo{

  String name;
  String id;
  String orgtype;
  String subtype;
  String street;
  String city;
  String country;
  Coordinates coordinates;

  AccountInfo({this.name, this.id, this.orgtype, this.subtype, this.street, this.city, this.country, this.coordinates});

  factory AccountInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){

    return AccountInfo(
      name: json["Name"],
      id: json["TPA Customer ID"],
      orgtype: json["Organization Type"],
      subtype: json["Organization Subtype"],
      street: json["Street (Billing)"],
      city: json["City (Billing)"],
      country: json["State (Billing)"],
      coordinates: Coordinates.fromJson(json["Coordinate"])
    );
  }
}

class Coordinates{

  String lat;
  String lng;

  Coordinates({this.lat, this.lng});

  factory Coordinates.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){

    return Coordinates(
      lat: json["Latitude"],
      lng: json["Longitude"]
    );
  }
}
```

This is the dart file containing the list of accounts

**list.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:emas_app/model/accounts_model.dart';

Future<String> _loadAsset2() async{
  return await rootBundle.loadString('Assets/accounts.json');
}

//Working future for accounts
Future<Accounts> loadAccounts() async{

  final response = await _loadAsset2();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response);

  if(jsonResponse["State (Billing)"] == "Johor") {
    Accounts accounts = new Accounts.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    return accounts;
  }
}

class ProviderList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  ListState createState() {
    return new ListState();
  }
}

class ListState extends State<ProviderList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> widgets = [];

    widgets.add(new ExpansionTile(
        title: new Text("Johor"),
        children: <Widget>[
          new FutureBuilder<Accounts>(
              future: loadAccounts(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){

                  return new ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.accountinfo.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){

                        String username = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].name;
                        String address = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].street;
                        String lat = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].coordinates.lat;
                        String lng = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].coordinates.lng;

                        return new ListTile(
                            title: new Text(username),
                            trailing: new Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.info),
                                    onPressed: null
                                ),
                                new IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.directions),
                                    onPressed: null
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                        );
                      });
                }else{
                  return new Center(
                    child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              })
        ]));

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Providers")),
      body: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: widgets,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
I/flutter ( 6385): The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<Accounts>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 6385): _FutureBuilderState<Accounts>#a326f):
I/flutter ( 6385): A build function returned null.
```

I am trying to see if I could sort the JSON by their states (billing) in the Future method but it returns null. If i am doing it normally without the sort part it works just fine.

Is there some other method or a fix that I could implement?

Answer (score 1):

[`List.sort`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html) sorts the list itself and returns nothing(void), thats the reason for the issue. You can apply the sort to the accountInfo like this and it should work

```
if(jsonResponse["State (Billing)"] == "Johor") {
    Accounts accounts = new Accounts.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    accounts.accountinfo.sort((a, b) {
      return a.country.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.country.toLowerCase());
    });
    return accounts;
  }
```

Or, you can do it here

```
factory Accounts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
  var accJson = json["Accounts"] as List;
  List<AccountInfo> accList = accJson.map((i) => 
  AccountInfo.fromJson(i)).toList();
  accList.sort((a, b) {
      return a.country.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.country.toLowerCase());
    });
  return Accounts(
    accountinfo: accList
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried the way you proposed but it does not seem to work for some reason. Maybe I am not doing it properly. Will try again.

Comment: Yep, @mezoni, you are right. The sentencing is wrong, but the answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

The `List.sort` method always returns `null`. It's a `void` function, so if you see its value, you are somehow dodging the warning about using the value of a `void` expression, perhaps because your code is typed as `dynamic` at that point.

I'm notsure where you try to sort which list, but if you write `something.sort(compareFunction)` then it sorts the list and evaluates to `null`.
Try writing `something..sort(compareFunction)` instead. That will sort the list but the expression evalutes to the list, not the result of calling `sort`.

The `sort` function modifies the list. If you want the same list to be used in multiple places, you might not want each place to sort the list in its own way, and you should instead make a copy before sorting: `something.toList()..sort(compareFunction)`.